# Bootstrap put dropdown menu into image

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to insert a button with a dropdown menu in a picture.
To create a hover effect I relied on this plugin: http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/

Everything works after the necessary precautions css, but I get an unsatisfactory result, ie dropdown menu remains inside the image instead of being on top of the image, the wrong thing because if the image is too close the menu is cut!
There is a better way to get the result?

```
<img class="hov" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x120/a26/fff" />
           <div class="contenthover">
               <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle mybutton" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Modifica</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Imposta come predefinito</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Elimina immagine</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="conhov">
                        <p>Description</p>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/Aa9Qd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  top: -1px;
  width: 84%;
  left: 3px;
}
```

Feel free to play around with it

Comment: Thank you!
The problem is that the image can vary in width ..
The best thing would be that the menu came out from the image outside.
Because otherwise each image close the menu would be illegible.

Comment: well that plugin of yours adds an `overflow:hidden` to the container it creates. you could overwrite it with `.ch_hover{overflow:visible !important;}` and then change the location of the dropdown to where you want it